# How to renew ios distribution certificate

Tags: ios, app-store

I got a mail from apple that regarding ios distribution certificate.I tried to revoke but there is no revoke button in distribution certificate
delete,edit,download options are there what should i do should i wait till certificate expires

This certificate will no longer be valid in 30 days. To create a new certificate, visit Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in your account.

Certificate: iOS Distribution

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if you have any doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificate expires automatically from 365 days of creating. You can see when you create new one. Its best to create new one once it is expired.

For revoking go to production and click on certificate and dropdown option will come to revoke. Apple Developer Center->Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles->Production->Certificate(i.e for revoke)

[image: Revoke Distribution]

Comment: so should i wait for expiry,will it effect my current live apps?

Comment: it depend if you are developing app and don't want one day your build to stop working. Best is to create new one and start using that one. And if app is already in store. Then you don't need to create new one, just bcoz it's expiring. As certificates are  required for sending build or uploading app.

Comment: I have a build in appstore. Now my certificate is going to expire. Shall I need to create a new build with newly created certificate